# Input Mask in a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox in Microsoft Access 2010 how do I make that column 5 should have a input mask?

Answer (score 2):

A listbox does not accept data entry, especially in column 5, so even if you could have an input mask, it would be of no use to you. If you want the column to have a particular format, you can use a format:

```
 Row Source: SELECT f1,f2,f3,f4, Format(f5,"\Str00.00")
```

More on format: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx